# Parse on Heroku User Login Error

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, mlab

Migrating and existing Parse app to Heroku with mLab mongo database --

I have migrated my Parse application database to mLab and cloned the parse-starter-project and loaded it onto Heroku. Set the `DATABASE_URI` to my mlab db path and server to the heroku parse server url.

`strUserID` and `strPWD` values are set prior to the call.

When I try to log in to the Parse application using this iOS command:

```
 [PFUser logInWithUsername:strUserID password:strUserPWD error:&loginError];
```

I get the following error - saying that I have he wrong data format:

```
Vinoloco[4941:418950] Error Code = 3840
2017-02-02 18:31:33.894895 Vinoloco[4941:423700] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(10, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
2017-02-02 18:31:33.895468 Vinoloco[4941:423700] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1.1 54.243.231.184:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
2017-02-02 18:31:33.897111 Vinoloco[4941:423902] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
2017-02-02 18:31:33.897887 Vinoloco[4941:423700] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 10, 1024 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer
2017-02-02 18:31:33.963 Vinoloco[4941:418950] Error Desc = The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
(lldb)
```

Has anyone experience a similar error and any ideas on solving the problem?

Comment: Are you able to fetch anything from parse-server using MasterKey?

Comment: What is the code to fetch using the Master Key?  I have the key set to the one used before migration.  I have tried bypassing the login by enabling user autocreate: [PFUser enableAutomaticUser];  and then tried a fetch on one of the other columns (classes):     PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"vlRegistration"];
////    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"gfuller"];
//    
    NSArray *arrUsers = [query findObjects];
In the above, arrUsers is always = nil     @Haken Lid